# MapBox framework issue iOS using objective c

Tags: objective-c

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents
  Referenced from: /Users/priya/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DDBC14B2-4830-462A-B711-65C31C21644C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A86BFD27-9542-4329-9A13-D12373043531/trackofy.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
  Reason: image not found
Please tell me about the above issue as I am unable to resolve I cannot use Uses_frameworks as I am using dynamic framework in my project using objective c.

Please give me solution for the above problem

Comment: How did you installed MapBox? CocaoPods? Carthage? Manually? Are we supposed to guess?